# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid (Python 3.10 and PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

Below is the code of my program im having issues.

```
EXPERIMENT_NAME = args.exp_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_log = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')
    if int(args.log_time) :
        folder_name = 'paraphraser_{}'.format(time_log)

    #Error taking place at this point.
    path = os.path.join(EXPERIMENT_NAME, folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists('ckpt/' + path):
        os.makedirs('ckpt/' + path)
    if not os.path.exists('logs/' + path):
        os.makedirs('logs/' + path)

    # Save argparse arguments as logging
    with open('logs/{}/commandline_args.txt'.format(path), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(args.__dict__, f, indent=2)
    # Instantiate logger
    logger = SummaryLogger(path)
```

As for the Results where the Error taking place
[image]
Below is the file directory in Windows 11
[image]
If there is anyone with solution can you please help.

Solving the issue for directory so that the my python program can run.

Comment: you cannot have colons in file or folder names `:`

Comment: In windows , `:` is a drive or source marker. You cannot use them in file or folder names.